# Why event listener not working on Google map marker in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

Currently i am working on Google map but when i am giving click listener to the marker the event is not triggering.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

            View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.map_marker_layout, null);

            mNameLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.map_name_layout);

            mNameLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

Please kindly go through my code and suggest me some solution.

Comment: Is it that the `Toast` isn't shown?

Comment: hey thanks, no Toast is not showing

Comment: I'm not too sure about this, but you could try using `setClickable(true)` on your `mNameLayout` first.

Comment: no setClickable(true) is not working

Comment: You've mentioned that you've added click listener to your **marker**, but in code you've set it to your info window layout. Are you trying to click the marker or the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onMapReady Set onClick listner like this.

```
  googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Infowindow clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Marker Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

from your above code you are inflating map layout into getInfoWindow() and setting the click event on layout not on marker.

if you want to click on your map you need to try this-

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

                }
            });
}
```

and if you want to click on your map marker then you need to try this-

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
}
```